# How to use balanceOf function with Web3j for an android app

Tags: web3j, infura, android

I am trying to use the `balanceOf` function after the generation of our smart contract (pakoin) function wrappers in Java with Web3j. Despite trying different ways, I get plenty of errors and I don't know how to solve them.

First of all, I tried doing this way:

```
BigInteger balance = pakoin.balanceOf(publicKeyUser).send();

result= balance.toString();
```

However, instead of printing the balance, the app suddenly closes and I have the following error on the console:

> 12-30 10:47:55.215 29089-29105/com.daedasan.sgssi_pakos
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   Process: com.daedasan.sgssi_pakos, PID: 29089
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing
>   doInBackground()
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method
>   getTypeName()Ljava/lang/String; in class Ljava/lang/reflect/Type; or
>   its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.Type' appears in
>   /system/framework/core-oj.jar)
>   at org.web3j.abi.TypeReference.getClassType(TypeReference.java:54)
>   at
>   org.web3j.abi.FunctionReturnDecoder.build(FunctionReturnDecoder.java:99)
>   at
>   org.web3j.abi.FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(FunctionReturnDecoder.java:42)
>   at org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeCall(Contract.java:159)
>   at
>   org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeCallSingleValueReturn(Contract.java:165) 
>   at
>   org.web3j.tx.Contract.executeCallSingleValueReturn(Contract.java:176) 
>   at
>   org.web3j.tx.Contract.lambda$executeRemoteCallSingleValueReturn$1$Contract(Contract.java:232)
>   at org.web3j.tx.Contract$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
>   at org.web3j.protocol.core.RemoteCall.send(RemoteCall.java:30)
>   at
>   com.daedasan.sgssi_pakos.MainActivity$ReadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:199)
>   at
>   com.daedasan.sgssi_pakos.MainActivity$ReadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:181)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>   Enviado en:         11:49                                    Enviado
>   en:     11:49

Afterwards, based on an example I found online, I tried this way:

```
BigInteger balance = pakoin.balanceOf(publicKeyUser).sendAsync().get();

result= balance.toString();
```

This doesn't work either. I get the following exception:
[image: exception]

**Q:** Do you know how to solve this problem or another way to do it? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might find useful information in the following project.

https://github.com/web3j/web3j/tree/master/integration-tests/src/test

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is probably that you're not running a local ethereum node (which you could never do on android anyway) using most of the web3 functionality requires an ethereum node to connect to. Often this is a local instance of Geth or parity but you could also us a service like [infura](https://infura.io/). Then using somthing like `web3.setProvider(...)`(I haven't used Web3j, only web3.js so you'll have to read docs for details but if you search for 'provider' it should get you on the right track) Getting ethereum/web3 running on mobile can be pretty tricky